# How to use the Azure Table Storage - Insert Entity with dynamic content with Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want to insert a row into an Azure Table using the Azure Table Storage connector.  LA expects json in the body.  How do I use a dynamic expression in the json?

[image]

Comment: actual problem was I wasn't setting content-header to application/json in my postman and it was failing.  once I set content-header to application/json in my postman it worked great.

Answer (score 5):

You could insert `Dynamic content` in your json, I don't know how did you get your variables, so I just define a variable to test. The below are test flow and the result in the table.

[image]

[image]

You could also set other dynamic values and then what you should focus on is what your variable or other contents you get should be or how to set.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: @Joe Healy , if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer.Thanks!